# git: keep latest version of a file in repo, don't save history

Tags: git

I have a repo that includes several binary files, which are rather big for git (up to several 100 MBs).
I want to keep track of everything else via git and be able to clone that repo including those binaries. But i don't want the cumulative size of their blobs.

I can't keep the binaries outside the repo.
A separate Git-LFS server is no option, since the "remote" is just a bare repo on a smb network share/external drive.
The files already include their own versioning.

Is there any way I can push the newest version of those files to the remote, without saving the diff in history?

Comment: you want to add the file extension into your `.gitattribute` and flag it as binary

Comment: Given the restrictions, you might keep them in their own separate _"orphan"_ branch (single commit) that you can amend every time you want to replace the files. Rewriting history of the project branch just to remove their old history sounds like an overkill to me.

Comment: Maybe you should consider a local deployment of Git LFS? I don't know if it's any good, but https://github.com/sinbad/lfs-folderstore claims to provide Git LFS functionality with storage on a local shared drive, exactly for your use case.

Comment: Each commit in Git is a _full snapshot_ of the project's state at that point in time. "Not keeping the history for single files" would mean to rewrite (i.e. delete and recreate) all commits which contained these files. Recreating commits mean that their commit hash changes. Additionally, you couldn't check out old versions, because they would be missing some required files (even if you had the files, they would be in the wrong "version").

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can push the newest version of those files to the remote, without saving the diff in history

*No* diffs are saved in history. History consists entirely of commits, which are complete static snapshots of the state of the entire project (they are not diffs, or changes).

If the goal is to behave as if this file has no history, you would need to rewrite potentially all past commits to eliminate the file from them. That is not a tenable repeatable procedure going forward, but you could certainly do it once if you had to.